# Placeholder Issue in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hello, I have this issue in PBI and I don't understand why ?

tes2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(V_PBI_EOY[DATE_YYYYMMDD]),KEEPFILTERS([#DELTA_ORG_ACTUALS_METHOD_1] > [#DELTA_ORG_ACTUALS] || [#DELTA_ORG_ACTUALS_METHOD_1] > 1.149))

Someone can help me ?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with measure, how do you use it, what for?

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are using a function in a boolean condition.

E.g. **[#DELTA_ORG_ACTUALS_METHOD_1]**, which looks like a measure (function) should be a column reference ('Table'[Column]).